# Remove root from Firebase everytime controller is loaded

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning to use Firebase with AngularJS by creating a super simple todo app. Every time the controller is loaded into the page (basically every page refresh), I want the data on my Firebase to be removed completely (at root).

Here is a super basic `index.html` snippet:

```
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="task in tasks | orderBy: reverse:true">
          <input ng-model="task.text" ng-change="tasks.$save(task)" />
          <button ng-click="tasks.$remove(task)">Completed!</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      ...
      <form ng-submit="addTask()">
        <input ng-model="newTaskText" />
        <button type="submit">Add Task</button>
      </form>
      <br />
```

And here is the Firebase snippet in `app.js`

```
  var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("tasks"); 

  $scope.tasks = $firebaseArray(ref);
  $scope.addTask = function() {
    $scope.tasks.$add({
      text: $scope.newTaskText
    });
  };
```

The Firebase config itself is pretty simple:

```
tasks
|
|----KSOMERANDOMSTRINGvakdfaajkdsf
|          |-----text: "This is task 1"
|
|----SOMEOTHERRANDOMSTRINGkasmdfkls
           |-----text: "This is task 2"
```

This is what I have on `app.js` for root removal:

```
var firebaseRootRef = firebase.database().ref(); //points to root
$scope.roottasks = $firebaseArray(firebaseRootRef);
$scope.roottasks.$remove();
```

Currently, this broke down Angular. What is the best way to remove/ clear-up an entire root Firebase db on page load/refresh?